# Can panel model with time effect only be called one-way panel model?

Tags: panel-data, terminology, fixed-effects-model

One-way Fixed Effect panel model has typical functional form:

$$y_{it} = \alpha_i + \beta x_{it} +\varepsilon_{it} $$

where $\alpha_i$ represents unit-specific dummies.

Then, for this model:

$$y_{it} = \alpha_t + \beta x_{it} +\varepsilon_{it} $$

where $\alpha_t$ represents time-specific dummies: **Is it appropriate to call such model also a One-way Fixed Effect panel model?**

Comment: Sure. Labeling either specification a 'one-way' model is appropriate. If you're referring to it over and over again in a paper then dubbing either model a "fixed effects" estimator works as well, which might also save you later on if there's a tight word limit. If you want to get fancy, you could say the former model incorporates "unit-specific" intercepts, whereas the latter introduces "time-specific" intercepts. The paper recommended by @cure (answer below) is a very good read. It details all these different approaches in greater detail.

Comment: It is not wrong but as unit-specific one-way fixed effect models are most commonly just called (one-way) fixed effect models I would recommend to include a reference to time like in "one-way time fixed effect model" to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article "[Interpretation and identification of within-unit and cross-sectional variation in panel data models](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0231349)" by J. Kropko, R. Kubinec:

**Yes**, they define "one-way FE model" as a model which has in functional form "case-specific intercepts" (equation (1) in the article) or "time-specific intercepts" (equation (2)), bot not both of them. They call them also "case FE model" and the "time FE model". "Two-way FE model" has in functional form both of these effects (equation (3)).